# Spark Storm or Flink - Big Data analysis

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-storm, apache-flink, bigdata

Can anyone recommend me which technology can be explored if I am having a large data set in Cassandra table (3 node cluster) and I need to perform a sum operation on records received on daily basis. The count so calculated needs to be updated in a MySQL table.

```
 Steps to perform - 
 1. Fetch Ids from MY SQL table
 2. Run Sum operation from Cassandra table
 3. Insert/update the calculated sum value in MYSQL table
```

Currently I am using plain Java to perform these tasks using SQL and CQL queries but its very slow and in future data will be growing exponentially.

Can anyone suggest technologies that can be explored to get this task accomplish in fastest possible way and lowest development time.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

There's not much to recommend, it depends only on the task you have and your own preferences.

Apache Storm is a streaming engine, it would be good if you want to process stream of entries, not a batch of data like in your case.

Both Apache Spark and Apache Flink will allow you to perform batch job once a day or make a streaming application that will calculate results from one day.

I prefer Apache Spark, as it has unified API for batch and streaming jobs (so you can easily change code from batch to streaming) and strong community support. Apache Flink supports real time streaming, however it's not necessary in your case.

However, you should look and these two frameworks on your own and choose this framework, which looks better for you. In my opinion both of them will be ok